# Its is Possible to use .AddOperationalStore for PersistedGrants with .InMemoryResources/Cients?

Tags: identityserver4

I would like to store PersistedGrants in the database for the purpose of Azure Scale Out.

I prefer to read IdentityResources/ApiResources/Clients(Config) from appsettings.json rather than from database.

From the [How To on IdentityServer4's doc site](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) an example is shown to persist both to database.

Is it possible to not load configuration data into Database while storing Grants?  If so how?

This works:

```
        services.AddIdentityServer((options) =>
        {
            options.UserInteraction = new UserInteractionOptions
            {
                LoginUrl = "/login",
                LogoutUrl = "/api/Account/Logout",
                ErrorUrl = "/error"
            };
        })
       .AddSigningCredential(X509CertificateHelper.getCert(_env))            
       .AddOperationalStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
           options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))           
       .AddConfigurationStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
           options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
       .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

This doesn't.  Specifically I cannot run `dotnet ef database update -c PersistedGrantDbContext`.

```
        services.AddIdentityServer((options) =>
        {
            options.UserInteraction = new UserInteractionOptions
            {
                LoginUrl = "/login",
                LogoutUrl = "/api/Account/Logout",
                ErrorUrl = "/error"
            };
        })
        .AddSigningCredential(X509CertificateHelper.getCert(_env))           
        .AddOperationalStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(AppSettingsHelper.GetIdSrvrSettings()))
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

For the latter I get the following error:

> An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup
>   class 'Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the
>   initialization of the DbContext at design-time. Error: Cannot perform
>   runtime binding on a null reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Is it possible to not load configuration data into Database while
>   storing Grants? If so how?"

Yes it is. You're using EntityFrame work for your persistence so the info I give may not be fully compatible ... we use something else to manage db persistence.

Our `ConfigureServices` looks something like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(x =>
            {
                x.IssuerUri = webServerSettings.Host;
            })
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources());

services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
```

In this way our `IdentityResources`, `ApiResources` and `Clients` are pulled in from config files, and our `Grants` are managed with our own implementation of the `IPersistedGrantStore`. We're not doing anything special with that interface: it is a very straight-forward interface to implement with only a handful of simple methods to wire up.